# using output from mediainfo as variable in another command

Tags: file, batch-file, mediainfo

So I'm trying to setup an easy way of starting videos with a bat file, and having that run Mediainfo first to get the length of the video so it can then stop vlc or whatever else when it's done playing.

```
Complete name                            : C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Psych s05e11.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 116 MiB
Duration                                 : 42 min 36 s
Overall bit rate                         : 382 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf55.13.102
```

That's the output from mediainfo I got in a txt file, I'm trying to just pull the 42 and the 36 from the duration bit and use it in another command. I should also add that these numbers have to be used separately. Thanks!

Edit: Thanks for replying everyone love the help;
Here's what I'm trying to run now:

```
mediainfo.lnk --Language=raw --Output=General;%Duration% "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Psych s05e11.mp4"
```

and the output is:

```
2556249
```

Now I need a way to take the first four digits and use them in a another command, somehow make 2556 a variable?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? You can use FOR /F and FIND to solve this problem.

Comment: Kind of need to see how you are executing mediainfo before we can provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the duration, use e.g. this command:

```
mediainfo "--Output=General;%Duration%" YourFileName.ext
```

In a general way, when you think to some automation, prefer to use e.g.:

```
mediainfo -f --Language=raw  YourFileName.ext
```

and select the lines which better fits your need, avoid fields with "/String" because they are intended only for display (not for automation).

Jérôme, developer of MediaInfo.

Comment: I'm running the command like so: mediainfo --Language=raw --Output=General;%Duration% "filename.ext" >> "outputfile.txt" and I'm only getting the duration like I want, thanks for that help!

Comment: Here's a weird problem I've run into; when I run the command out of a terminal like I've shown in the last comment I get the proper output, however using the exact same command in a batch file returns an output without any options, it runs as: mediainfo --Output=file:\\file.txt "filename.ext". Giving too much information! What could I do to get around that?

Comment: Just to tell you (As developper) you shoul never use the `%` as var definer  in a CLI version of a soft. Better use another char like `$`. Anyway great soft !!

Comment: Not a problem of MediaInfo, this is a problem in your batch: % is used for variable, you forgot to escape it.

mediainfo "--Output=General;%%Duration%%" %1

Comment: You're right i forgot the "string", Modified My Answer, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `FOR /F`

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('mediainfo "--Output=General;%%Duration%%" "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Psych\s05e11.mp4"') do set $Duration=%%a

Echo %$Duration%
```

Using a temporary file

```
@echo off
mediainfo.exe --Language=raw --Output=General;%%Duration%% "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Psych s05e11.mp4" >out.txt  
set /p $Duration= <out.txt
set $Duration=%$Duration:~0,4%

echo Result = %$Duration%
del out.txt
```

Another way using @Jérôme Martinez [raw -output] idea.
Without temporary file, using `findstr` :

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('mediainfo -f --Language=raw  "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Psych s05e11.mp4" ^| findstr /i "duration"') do (
    set $Duration=%%a
    goto:next
)

:next
set $Duration=%$Duration:~1,4%
echo %$Duration%
```

Comment: Thanks for the help; Seems closer than anything I've got so far! However the echo output is: Result = ~0,4

Comment: Figured out the path was just set up wrong, got that situated now the output is: Result = Alte

Comment: Ok and when you just execute `mediainfo.lnk --Language=raw --Output=General;^%Duration^% "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Psych s05e11.mp4"` What is the exact output ? In all case you'll better work directly on the `.exe` and not on the .lnk

Comment: If I run it in a terminal I get the expected 2556249 but if I run that in a bat file the output is the huge list of stuff mediainfo would display by default, I'll try running it using the exe file instead

Comment: I've run it again using the exe file instead of a link, same output, long list of stuff I don't need. However if I do that command by itself it prints out just the Duration

Comment: Let me make a test

Comment: Looks as though %Duration% is being looked at like a variable rather than a command option. That's why the ^ right? They don't seem to be working.. anything else that might work?

Comment: I tried something like that myself, but don't understand batch enough to get anywhere near that! Thanks for that! Quick question is the ~0,4% the option to use only the first 4 digits?

Comment: check my new EDIT with the first solution, And put this Post as answered

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's what I did finally, thanks for all the help!

```
C:\mediainfo\MediaInfo.exe --Language=raw --Output=General;%%Duration%% "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Psych_s05e11.mp4" >out.txt  
set /p $Duration= <out.txt
set $Duration=%$Duration:~0,4%

echo Result = %$Duration%
del out.txt
pause
```

and the output is:

```
C:\mediainfo\MediaInfo.exe --Language=raw --Output=General;%Duration%    "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Psych_s05e11.mp4" >out.txt 
set /p $Duration=  <out.txt 
set $Duration=2556 
echo Result = 2556 
Result = 2556
del out.txt 
pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

took @echo off outta there so you could see it all